# Interaction between 2 scripts to get picture and description

Tags: php

I have 2 scripts who works correctly

The first one get info from bdd and insert them into my page

```
<div class="bloq">
<?php
// condition texte   // on fait une boucle du tableau pour l'affichage
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 { 
 ?> 
 $premiereEntree=($pageActuelle-1)*$messagesParPage; // On calcule la première entrée à lire
 // recherche du texte
 require_once("db_connect_mysqli.php");
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM produits";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>
<div class="bloq">
<?php
// condition texte   // on fait une boucle du tableau pour l'affichage
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 { 
 ?> 
<table>
<tr><td>
<!-- affichage de l'image ici (picture here)--> 
</th></td></tr>
<tr><td>
  <?php 
 $desc= $row['name'];
  echo chunk_split($desc,45,"<br/>") ;
  ?>
</tr></td>
<tr><td>
  <?php   
  echo  $row['price']; echo '€';
  ?>
</tr></td>
</table>
<?php
  } //fin while row       
  $row ='' ;
  $path ='' ;
  $img ='' ;
  ?>
</div> <!-- fin div class bloc-->
 
<tr><td>
```

the second search picture and put it into the page

```
$repertoire = "upload/";
  $iteration = opendir($repertoire); 
 while ($fichier = readdir($iteration))
 {
  $fichier_info = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
  $mime_type = finfo_file($fichier_info, $repertoire.$fichier);
    echo '<img src="'.$repertoire.$fichier.'" alt="">'; 
} //fin while
lister_images("upload/");
```

what I want is many table including picture with under of it the description and the price
the picture name must be the same than description name ( I have a script who rename the picture as the name when I record it) like this: picture link here:
[image: picture link here]

Trouble is if I just let the echo its only the same picture price and description ( the while doesn't seams to work correctly)

Comment: So what's the connection between the two snippets? `<!-- affichage de l'image ici (picture here)-->` - is that supposed to be the location where the second one is embedded/included? _"the while doesnt seams to work correctly"_ - it just reads the whole folder content, it doesn't contain any selection of one specific image. Why are you using that loop anyway? If your images are named after the description of the product - then you should _know_ the name already, no? So you should be able to output `<img src="name-based-on-description-goes-here">` directly.

Comment: Or is there an issue that you have to handle different image formats, and therefor file name suffixes? In that case, you should probably read the folder content into an array once, so that you can then search for the matching image in there.